# Firebase rules restrict writing not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to restrict editing the "version" child in my database, but somehow rules are not working. Here is my code in rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "version": {
       ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

In rules playground, it somehow skips the rule defined for specific child and reads rule for global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here you defined rules for parent (globally) as true and you are trying to limit the access at its child level (locally) so by default it will take attributes of parent for access. Instead what you can do is if you want to allow access for reading for all childs and limit the write access to specific child you can define rules like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "version": {
       ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

so if you add any more childs and want to give them some special access

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "version": {
       ".write": false
    },
    "data": {
       ".write": true
     }
  }
}
```

lets say you want to limit the read access of second child so instead of defining rules globally you will define them for each child

```
{
  "rules": {
    "version": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": false
    },
    "data": {
       ".read": false,
       ".write": true
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works for the version, I cannot edit it anymore. But I cannot edit anything else, and that's not what I want. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: For example, I have 2000+ childs with randomly generated names and I want to enable writing for them. How can I do that?

Comment: "For example, I have 2000+ childs with randomly generated names and I want to enable writing for them." That is a different question from your original, but you'll want to look at wildcards for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables

Comment: or else you can use firebase's admin sdk to to deploy rules dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! You solved my problem!